# What does __interceptor_strchr do?

Tags: c, stack, stack-smash, machine-code, thttpd

my function crashes(due to stack overrun) right after this machine instruction:

```
0x00000000004b1e4c <read_config+188>:  e8 3f 85 fa ff  callq  0x45a390 <__interceptor_strchr(char const*, int)>
```

What does `__interceptor_strchr(char const*, int)` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like part of [LLVM's AddressSanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) error detector.